# Media queries and percentage width causes strange IMG shrinking behaviour on webkit browsers

Tags: css, webkit, responsive-design, media-queries

If you load the following webpage code into Chrome (and smartphones) you will get a very strange shrinking behaviour on the img that occurs everytime the viewport crosses the 440px breakpoint.  You can replicate the problem by repeatedly resizing your chrome browser smaller and then larger than 440px wide, or on your smartphone by switching back and forth between portrait and landscape.  It's actually quite hilarious when you do it several times until the image gets so small it literally just vanishes!! LOL!

Anyone know what is causing this strange behaviour and a way around it?  Notable that it doesn't happen in FireFox.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
  <style>
    #supported-payment-options li {
      float:left;
      list-style:none;
    }
    @media (max-width: 679px) {
      img.retina-zoom { width:75%; }
    }
    @media (max-width: 440px) {
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="supported-payment-options">
    <li><img class="retina-zoom" src="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1695501054/book-responsive_reasonably_small.gif"></li>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like the 440px media query is somehow "double applying" the 75% everytime the breakpoint is hit.  Why?!  It's retarded

Comment: Another Chrome/WebKit bug, huh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha!, that is a funny effect. To fix it, use `max-width` rather than `width`:

```css
@media (max-width: 679px) {
  img.retina-zoom { max-width:75%; }
}
```

**Edit:** Note this doesn't happen in the latest [Webkit Nightly](http://nightly.webkit.org/) so perhaps it's a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: @SampleJACK glad to help. By the way, excellent [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) in your question.